# Cannot capture image from virtual signature HTML5 canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using this as a virtual signature pad: http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/ . It can either automatically generate a signature from a typed name or let the user sign with their mouse. I need to capture the image and send it to a Java server. It uses an HTML5 canvas.

It works correctly for the drawn image, but trying to capture the automatically generated image results in a blank image with no text.

I am using this code as it said in the site's API section:

```
var api = $('.sigPad').signaturePad();                  
autoGeneratedData = api.getSignatureImage();
```

and then sending `autoGeneratedData` to the server.

I also tried to capture the canvas directly:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('sigCanvas');                  
var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

but ran into the same issue.

Comment: The goal is to send it to a java server, but I don't think it's a relevant factor in this question.